# Useing a 32bit Service to start 64bit version of cscript

Tags: visual-studio, service, wow64

So what I am trying to accomplish is to always start. cscript.exe in native os version. SO I have access to the correct system files when my script runs and won't be redirected to the syswow64 regestry/files.

So according the msdn docs i can use the sysnative when running a 32bit application on a  64bit system to get the real system32 folder. But the script cant seam to find the the cscript.exe file. So the question is what am i doing wrong? I mostly a python guy so I might be making a stupid assumption.

This is compiled into a 32bit Service, so it could be deployed on any windows os(in theory)

Running VisualStudio 2010 if it matters

Or am I approaching the problem completely back to front?

```
Public Class Service1

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    'Prvents windows from redirecting us to the wow64 folder instead of system32.

    ' Don' run if settings file is gone
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Settings.vbs") Then

        'If we are running in wow64(32bit windows files) mode switch to native 64 bit vbscript
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("%systemroot%\sys­native") Then
            Process.Start("%systemroot%\sys­native\cscript.exe", "C:\Main.vbs")
        Else
            Process.Start("%systemroot%\system32\cscript.exe", "C:\Main.vbs")

        End If



    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
End Sub

End Class
```

Basicly to the question is How do I get cscript to run in 64bit mode rather than 32bit, so only really this line.

Process.Start("%systemroot%\system32\cscript.exe", "C:\Main.vbs")

That gets changed to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 when run a on a 64 bit system.

But stays on 32bit system it stays  C:\Windows\system32.

I also tried this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365744%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But I cant seam to figure out how to make it work. In a vb application

Answer (score 0):

Answer over there

Option Infer On

Option Strict On

Imports System.IO Module Module1 Sub Main() Dim f As String = "" If IntPtr.Size = 4 Then f = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%"), "sysnative") MsgBox("Running on X86") Else f = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) MsgBox("Running on X64") End If Dim wscript As String = Path.Combine(f, "wscript.exe") Dim psi = New ProcessStartInfo psi.FileName = wscript psi.Arguments = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "CheckPlatform.vbs") Dim p As New Process p.StartInfo = psi p.Start() End Sub End Module

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/48bc23b5-798f-4cea-ae33-060a0d66506b